# Invision Community - OAuth и получение токена

Tags: curl, oauth

Всем привет. столкнулся с проблемой OAuth авторизации и получения токена.

При настройке OAuth-client в СР я получил id & secret
пример:

```
CLIENT CREDENTIALS
Client Identifier  Wduhiauiadad897daas00
Client Secret  kjadajdh89a7dasdas7d89asd0a0da0s7dasd
Authorization Endpoint  https://www.dom.com/oauth/authorize/
Token Endpoint  https://www.dom.com/oauth/token/
```

возможно это глупо. Но все же: как мне теперь авторизироваться через OAuth и как получить токен (поясните Боту плиз)
Мне нужно работать с АПИ, по любезности разработчиков большая часть ф-ла только через OAuth
при попытке авторизации я получаю такие варианты:

- access denied
- error 400
- unsupported grant_type
- запрос проходит успешно но в ответе ничего нет (201)

Документацию уже все перелопатил, а "техподдержка" отправила на форум искать другую "поддержку".

доки: [дока-1](https://invisioncommunity.com/developers/rest-api?endpoint=forums/forums/POSTindex), [дока-2](https://invisioncommunity.com/4guides/developing-plugins-and-applications/rest-api_370/sending-your-first-request-r167/), [дока-3](https://invisioncommunity.com/developers/docs/legacy-documentation/login-handlers/creating-other-login-handlers-such-as-oauth-r68/), [дока-4](https://invisioncommunity.com/developers/docs/members-authentication/login-methods/creating-an-oauth-based-handler-r176/)

пример запроса

```
curl POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://www.dom.com/oauth/authorize/ -d "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=Wduhiauiadad897daas00&client_secret=kjadajdh89a7dasdas7d89asd0a0da0s7dasd"
```

подскажите может я что то не правильно делаю в запросе, подсказку желательно в виде CURL-request.

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел свою ошибку и решение. с помощью вот этой [доки](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/oauth-2-ru) Спасибо тем кто ее написал - это помогло досконально разобраться с системой OAuth. Как и предполагал 50% ошибки в моем запросе, а остальное связано с настойкой OAuth сервера в IPS Comunity.

```
curl POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://www.dom.com/oauth/token/ -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=Wduhiauiadad897daas00&client_secret=kjadajdh89a7dasdas7d89asd0a0da0s7dasd&scope=profile"
```

***scope=profile*** - в принципе он может быть и другим тк. его в любом случае нужно вручную настраивать в СР IPS Comunity